# If statement using both && and || operators

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I know this has been discussed plenty. I'm pretty sure I'm using proper operator precedence but am still not getting desired results.

In the code below I'm trying to to see if the body has the class "industries" AND if `window.location.href` is equal to any of the paths separated by `||` operators. If the class "industries" is present and `window.location.href` is not equal to any of the paths listed then I want to change the location.

What's happening though is when I enter the path as 
http://blahblah.com/#leisure 
It's still executing the code in the `if` statement and changing the location to https://blahblah.com/#consumer

I have a feeling my explanation is convoluted and messy. Sorry.

```js
var indDescObj = {
    aec: "Connecting with <br> customers who build",
    b2b: "Connecting <br> business to business",
    consumer: "Connecting <br> with shoppers <br> everywhere they buy",
    leisure: "Connecting with <br> customers when <br> they're at play"
}
    var $indDescription = $('.industry-description');
    var $indNavLinks = $('.industry-nav__link');

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var path = 'http://blahblah.com/'
        if ( $('body').hasClass('industries') &&
                        ( (window.location.href !== path + '#consumer') ||
                        (window.location.href !== path + '#b2b') ||
      (window.location.href !== path + '#leisure') ||
      (window.location.href !== path +'#aec') )
                        ) {
            $(".industry-nav__link[data-filter='.consumer']").click();
            window.location.href = "http://blahblah.com/#consumer";
        };
        var hashPath = "." + window.location.hashPath.slice(1);
        var pathObjKey = path.slice(1);
        $(".industry-nav__link[data-filter='" + hash + "']").addClass("is-active")
        $('.industry-description').append(indDescObj[pathObjKey])
})
```

Comment: Please have a read of [mcve].  It looks like you're asking about 5 lines but you've included 3x as many which makes it very hard to find exactly what you're referring it.

Comment: 1) `a !== SOMETHING  || a !== SOMETHING_ELSE` always evaluates to true; 2) consider checking `location.hash` instead.

Comment: *`AND if window.location.href is equal to any of the paths`* Your code is checking if the window.location.href is NOT_EQUAL to the paths.

Comment: Your `if` says:  "if it has .industries and...  it doesn't end with #consumer or it doesn't end with #b2b..."  will always be true (as you've found).    consider: 
 `var a = 1;  if (a!=1 || a!=2) .. ` if it's `1` then it's not `2` so will pass - if it's `2` then it's not `1` so will pass  - if it's anything else, then it will pass.

Comment: Cant you just do if within if (based on the logic I see)? `if ( $('body').hasClass('industries')) { if(...)}` - think about the next guy/gal who'd spend 10 mins trying to figure what exactly the logic is.

Comment: @freedomn-m I understand but when the if statement gets so long, its best to simplify than to add more confusion

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `||` you should be using `&&`. In other words you are saying *body has class and location is not A and location is not B etc then do something*.

Comment: Or keep the `||` and change `!==` to `==`

Comment: @Draco18s if you did that you'd have to add a `!` at the start, ie `(!a&&!b)` === `!(a||b)`

Comment: It depends, the question asked "if the hash equals one of several paths." If he's mistakenly used `!=`, then that's what needs to change.

Comment: Look at the example given.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others already, the problem is with your ! and || combination. The solution is to replace the || with &&.

Instead of comparing for each value, you can put it in an array on the fly an compare it.

eg:

```
    if (<firstcondition> && $.inArray(window.location.href, ['<value1>', '<value2>', '<value3>', '<value4>']) == -1) {
//body    
}
```

go through this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to know how it works.